# The format Dropdown list comes with kendo editor is not showing properly. Only shows when it does not have space to open downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

When I click the format it kind of get locked and can not type anything in the editor after. This happens when format button is in the middle of the page.
[image]

As below, if the format dropdown do not have space in the down then it appears perfectly.
[image]

same thing happen in the image upload.
[image]

[image]

Got source codes from here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/imagebrowser

This is the code I have added to implement the kendo editor

```
$(function () {
    $("#quest").kendoEditor({
        
        imageBrowser: {
            transport: {
                read: "@Url.Action("Read", "ControlerName")",
                destroy: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Destroy", "ControlerName")",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Create", "ControlerName")",
                    type: "POST"
                },
         thumbnailUrl: "@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "ControlerName")",
         uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("Upload", "ControlerName")",
         imageUrl: "@Url.Action("Image?path={0}", "ControlerName")",
            }

        },
        tools: [
            "formatting",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "underline",
            "superscript",
            "subscript",
            "justifyLeft",
            "justifyCenter",
            "justifyRight",
            "VerticalAlignTop",
            "Vertical-AlignTop",
            "Verticaltop",
            "insertUnorderedList",
            "insertOrderedList",
            "indent",
            "outdent",
            "insertImage",
            "createTable",
            "addRowAbove",
            "addRowBelow",
            "addColumnLeft",
            "addColumnRight",
            "deleteRow",
            "deleteColumn"            
        ]
      
    })"
```

Comment: upgrade the kendo editor and some UI changes resolved the issue